# RetroPie :: channelf: there's no theme.xml for this system

Tags: retropie

I was following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wc4daHBLNE) that helps you setup the ES Theme `TRONKYFRAN`.

I tried multiple times but at the end of the setup I always receive this error:

> Launching images generation for "tronkyfran" theme completed!
>
> Failed to create image for the following systems: channelf: there's no
> theme.xml for this system

[image]

What am I doing wrong?